# makedepend equivalent for use with nmake?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, makefile, nmake

Just wondering if there is a 'makedepends' equivalent that ships with visual studio that I can use with nmake.  Does anyone know?

Answer (score 9):

You can use the [`/showIncludes` switch to `cl.exe`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hdkef6tk(VS.80).aspx) to list the headers `#include`d by your source files.  Nested includes are indicated by indentation with spaces.  You can also turn on syntax-checking mode with the `/Zs` switch, to increase speed and avoid creation of .obj files.

If you have Perl and a version of `uniq` (e.g. from [GnuWin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/)) installed, the following one-liner will dump the list of unique headers used by `myfile.cpp`:

```
cl /Zs /showIncludes /EHsc myfile.cpp | perl -ne "print if s/^Note: including file: *//" | sort | uniq
```

It should not be too difficult to pipe this through another script that creates the relevant `nmake` rules.

Comment: This is perfect. I have been looking for that `/Zs` for so long. I though preferred using a combination of `grep -v` and `sed` than `perl`.

Comment: Let me go try to find where I buried Perl in the back garden...

Answer (score 5):

I assume you use NMAKE to build project like me.  I'm in need of makedepend-like tool in Windows, too.  So, I use MinGW to generate header dependencies.  First create Makefile to generate dependencies, which I named it Makedepends, like this:

```
    OBJS=... list object files in your project...

    all: Makefile.deps

    Makefile.deps: $(OBJS:.obj=.dep)
        cat $+ > $@
        rm -f $+

    %.dep: %.cpp
        g++ -MM -MG -MT$(@:.dep=.obj) -o$@ $<
```

In your Makefile that will be used by NMAKE, add this line at bottom:

```
    !INCLUDE Makefile.deps
```

When you want to create dependencies, run GMAKE like this:

```
    make -fMakedepends
```

And then, you can build your project with NMAKE as usual:

```
    nmake
```

PS: Sorry for poor language, I'm suck at writing. -_-

Answer (score 5):

```
.SUFFIXES:
.SUFFIXES: .c

all: x.obj

# Sample batch-mode rule which both compiles and produces .dep files suitable for NMAKE.
# Also works around the fact that CL.EXE spits diagnostics in stdout instead of stderr.
# This is equivalent to -MD -MP -MT$@ -MF$(@R).dep in GNU Make + GCC.
CCOMMAND = $(CC) $(CFLAGS) /c $<
.c.obj::
!IF "$(MAKEFLAGS:S=)" == "$(MAKEFLAGS)"
    @echo " $(CCOMMAND)"
!ENDIF
    @$(COMSPEC) /E:ON /V:ON /C "$(CCOMMAND) /showIncludes & echo Exit: !ERRORLEVEL!" | \
        $(COMSPEC) /E:ON /V:ON /C "for /f "tokens=1,* delims=]" %%A in ('find /v /n ""') do \
        @if %%~xB == .c (set _=%%~nB&rem.>!_!.dep&echo %%B) else for /f "tokens=1,2,3,*" %%C in ("%%B") do \
        @if %%C == Note: ((echo !_!.obj: "%%F"&echo "%%F":) >> !_!.dep) \
        else if %%C == Exit: (exit /b %%D) else echo %%B"

# Include the generated deps.
!IF ![(for %i in (*.dep) do @echo !INCLUDE %i) >Build.tmp]
!       INCLUDE Build.tmp
!       IF ![del Build.tmp]
!       ENDIF
!ENDIF
```

Comment: This should be on display in the "Museum of CMD Heroes"! (BTW, would be nice to have it extended for `.cpp`, too. That would need a bit more of the same poison, as there's no `OR` in this language, and the only person possibly willing to convert it to nested "if not"s may be the same one, who did that thing in the answer.)