# Generate Makefile dependency from MSVC output

Tags: c++, batch-file, visual-c++, makefile

While compiling a C/C++ source using GCC additional dependency info can be created in a Makefile rule form using the flags `-MMD -MT $@ -MF $(basename $@).d`. I made my Makefile script compatible with GCC and MSVC toolchains, but i still strugle with the dependency file generation on MSVC.
There is a flag `/showIncludes`
that outputs source file include information in stdout in the following form `Note: including file: filename`. Trying to parse it (so far successfully) i got as far as the following makefile function:

```
msvc-dep-gen =  echo $@: $< |\
    sed -e "s/^.*$$/&\\/" >$(basename $@).d && \
    $(1) /showIncludes |\
    sed -e "/^Note: including file:/!d"\
        -e "s/^Note: including file:\s*\(.*\)$$/\1/"\
        -e "s/\\/\//g"\
        -e "s/ /\\ /g"\
        -e "s/^\(.*\)$$/\t\1 \\/" >> $(basename $@).d
```

Where the parameter $(1) is the wrapped command to compile the given source file with MSVC. This generates the dependency file fine, but the output is filtered out so i lose all the warnings and the error exits produced by the compiler. Any clever ideas on how to prevent this?

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2987298/is-there-dependency-generation-flag-for-msvc-like-gccs-m

Answer (score 0):

If you put this in a shell script with `set -e` at the top, then failures will result in exiting with a non-zero code, and Make will see it.