# Automatic dependency tracking with NMAKE

Tags: dependencies, makefile, nmake

Is possible to detect automatically source dependency in a NMake makefile using VS 2005 compiler (as actually possible with GNU make and GCC compiler)?

Look at the '-M' option of [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.5.1/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#Preprocessor-Options). Including the outputted text of GCC in the makefile cause to automatically track source dependencies without maintaining them, since the GCC invocation can be automated using a phony target.

Comment: what do you mean, exactly?  Can you give an example?

Comment: possible duplicate of [makedepend equivalent for use with nmake?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/946105/makedepend-equivalent-for-use-with-nmake)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [makedepend equivalent for use with nmake?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/946105/makedepend-equivalent-for-use-with-nmake)